# Can you create your own top-level cgroup?

Tags: centos, cgroups

[The docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/cgroups.txt) seem to suggest this should work

```
# mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/mytest
# mount -t cgroup mytest  /sys/fs/cgroup/mytest
mount: /sys/fs/cgroup/mytest: mytest already mounted or mount point busy.
```

What am I missing?

This is cgroups-v1 on centos-8.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this (the paths may differ from my example since I'm on a different Linux version):

```
Create the cgroup
# mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/unified/mytest

Put the shell in the cgroup
# echo $$ > /sys/fs/cgroup/unified/mytest/cgroup.procs

Verify that the shell process is in the given cgroup
# cat /proc/$$/cgroup | grep mytest
0::/mytest
```

Comment: Yeah, no, centos-8 doesn't have a pre-existing "unified" cgroup. If I just create one from scratch without mounting it as `-t cgroup` then it's just a regular directory.